# wpf style ,how to reference border's borderbrush to background

Tags: wpf, styles

there is a border ,and i want to change it's border color and background color at the same time.
so , i define a style bellow

```
<Style x:Key="EoE" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGreen}"/>
<Setter Property="Background">
    <Setter.Value>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=BorderBrush }"  Opacity="1"/> 
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Effect">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="White"  Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="10"/>
        <!--<BlurEffect Radius="3" RenderingBias="Quality"/>-->
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
```

what i want to change at runtime is the borderbrush ,then i want the background solidcolorbrush changes at same time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to define another brush with another `Opacity` for the `Background` property of the Border, you could try this:

```
<Style x:Key="EoE" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="bgBrush" Color="{Binding Path=BorderBrush.(SolidColorBrush.Color), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border}}" Opacity="0.7"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGreen}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource bgBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="White"  Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="10"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
</Style>
```

If you just want to set the `Background` to the exact same brush as the `BorderBrush`, you could go with the solution provided by @ASh :

```
<Style x:Key="EoE" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LightGreen}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background"  Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" Color="White"  Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="10"/>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3):

make a binding with `RelativeSource Self`:

```
<Setter Property="Background" 
        Value="{Binding Path=BorderBrush, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}"/>
```